# Why is browser.min.js needed in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m trying to build a simple React application and am wondering why I need the browser.min.js file.

I have included both react and react-dom.js, but nothing is displayed unless  browser.min.js is also included.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="react/react.js"></script>
    <script src="react/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you can see in your snippet, the script tag is of type "text/babel", and that's because you are coding using JSX (Javascript with XML on it) inside it.

[JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/) is coding sugar created to make it more "intuitive" to build XML (HTML in this case) components in javascript code (not only React elements, though). React makes use of it as an abstraction layer over the composition methods used to create/define UI elements. **But** JSX is not a globally accepted standard, so it isn't supported by all browsers. This is the reason that you need a third party "compiler" library to transform the JSX to vanilla JS, and this is where [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/) comes through.

[BABEL](https://babeljs.io/) is a javascript compiler, and importing its "browser.min.js" file, you are enabling it to "compile" the code inside "text/babel" script tags and execute it as vanilla javascript.

So, in your example, you have the next code:

```
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
</script>
```

And "browser.min.js" will process it when the page has loaded and the javascript code that will be executed should be something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement('H1', null, 'Hello world!'), 
  document.getElementById('example'));
```

The main alternatives you have if you don't want to load this "browser.min.js" are:

1. Have your React code in separate files and compile them whenever you make a change (all of this is server-side). Your html code should reference the compiled files (which should have only vanilla JS code) instead of your original JSX ones. There are several ways to do this [depending on your coding tools](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/).
2. Use only vanilla JS to create and define your React "Html" hierarchy (React.createElement(...)).

Explaining in more detail these methods should be covered in other questions.

Comment: I have another question: what I always see if people using `var React = require('react');` in their files. And I've read that `webpack` is the tool that we use to work with these `require` commands. How does this play along here? Would I still need to have my react code (JSX) in a separate file (including `require` lines) > compile it to convert to regular JS > use webpack? Is there an easier / alternative process that doesn't include that extra step?

Comment: You really don´t need to use `webpack` at all. That's only if you want to create a single ".js" file that contains all the code from all your dependencies (and your actual code) instead of using multiple `<script src="...">` and making sure they are in the right order.

If you are being careful in your html and you are including all your dependencies (to say, a reference to the React CDN, or a local copy) you can/should delete that line `var React = require('react');`.

Comment: I suppose react's JSX is in now way related to this JSX: https://jsx.github.io/ ?

Comment: Just in the name, and that they both refer to the use of XML syntax embedded into javascript code, but the way it has to be processed it's completely different.

Answer (score 3):

You've written the code in Babel (ES7) and not in a version of JavaScript that the browser can handle natively, and you are delivering the ES7 to the browser instead of transpiling it at build time.

Comment: I think JSX isn't part of ES7 specification, though babel 'browser.min.js' compiles it to React createElem methods.

Answer (score 3):

Found that Babel's own 'browser.js' isn't working anymore?

['browser.js' was deprecated](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3710) back in 2015, meaning that continuing to be able to compile in-browser JSX became a little bit tougher.

Thankfully, the [babel-standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-standalone) project is a drop-in replacement, and appears to be in active development.

'babel-standalone' seems to be [endorsed by the BabelJS project itself, noted by its inclusion on this page](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation).