# React js tomcat, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, tomcat, reactjs

I am new to react js, i am trying to create react js based simple page using export and import functionality. Below is the description

1. App.jsx

   ```
   import React from '../build/react'

   export default class App extends React.Component {
       render() {
           return (
               <div>
                   Hello World!!!
               </div>
            );
          }
       }
   ```
2. main.jsx

   ```
   import {ReactDOM} from '../build/react-dom'
   import {App} from 'App'

   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
   ```
3. test.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">

        <script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
         <script src="custom/main.jsx"></script>
     </head>

   </html>
   ```

I have deployed it on tomcat, when i am trying to access "test.html" from browser it is giving me

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import at main.jsx : 1**

Please help me, whether i have missed anything in this.

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696601/why-is-browser-min-js-needed-in-reactjs

Comment: `import` and `export` will not work natively in the browser.

Comment: Thanks Davin for your quick reply. What i need to do to run this example?

Comment: You need a bundler, look at Webpack or something similar

Comment: Thanks let me try the same.

Comment: Webpack don't support import syntax yet (lover then version 2). You should use babel with es2015 and react plugins

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I did all that I could to solve it but to no avail. I deleted `node_module` from `C:` and issued `npm install` to reinstall `node_module` but still no solution.

I replaced my `package.json` with

```
{
    "name": "react-frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and replaced my `index.js` with

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I later made changes to them to suit my app's requirements. It worked perfectly - I can't explain how it happened.